# connection timeout

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-timeout

My method executes lots of asynchronous SQL requests and I constantly get connection timeout exceptions. What else can I do except increasing the connection timeout value and proper indexing? I mean with the database part, not with the code part. Can't change the code part. Besides, the application is running fine on different servers, but only I experience those timeout exceptions on my pc and local MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database (which is also on the same PC). So I think this is clearly a performance issue since the connection timeout is already set to 3 minutes. Maybe there is something I can change on the server? Maybe there is a number of simultanious requests constraint? Each of my requests needs clearly less that 3 minutes, but there are about 26 000 of them running asynchroniously, and only I experience those problems on my local PC and local DB.
I've run the process monitor and I see that at the time when my code starts the SQL Server eventually consumes 200 MB of RAM and takes up about a half of CPU processing time. But I still have 1 GB of RAM free, so this is not a memory problem.

Comment: Are you experiencing Connection Timeout or Command Timeout? You might be opening too many connections to SQL Server?

Comment: @Chris Diver I am experiencing connection timeout. Yes, I am openning too many connections, but I can't change that.

Comment: An update: I have a command timeout set, not the connection timeout. I'll try to set the connection timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I think the number of connection can be the cause. Make sure you close the connection properly or try to reduce the amount of them. You can also use pipes, which will overcome the limitations of usual connections.